# instanceOfFunction? A way to determine if a function has been created inside of the library

Tags: javascript, function, instanceof

I need to create a function inside of a library. Then I need to know if that function is that kind.

Y create a function more or less this way:

```js
function createSpecialFunction(somedata) {
    return function thisIsMySpecialFunction(...args) {
      ...
    }
}

const mySpecialFunction = createSpecialFunction(somedata)
```

Then I need a way to determine if `mySpecialFunction` is been created using `createSpecialFunction`. Something like

```js
mySpecialFunction instanceof createSpecialFunction // true
(()=>{}) instanceof createSpecialFunction // false
```

Comment: For what purpose do you need to do this check exactly? How much duck typing would you be fine with?

Comment: The checking does not have to be using instanceof. It would be an internal function of the library that checks if is a correct function or not.

Comment: Sure. So what does make a function "correct", what makes a function "incorrect"? How does it need to behave? What makes it special? The origin where it was created should normally not matter.

Comment: I just need to determine if my api has created the function or not. So I need to invent a way to identify if is special. The WeakSet solution you gave could be a good solution.

Comment: No, *why* do you care whether it was your api or not? What if some other api created the exact same function? Again: what makes it "special"?

Answer (score 2):

Save some flag in the function object that you are creating:

```
function createSpecialFunction(somedata){
    let thisIsMySpecialFunction = function(...args){
       ...
    }
    thisIsMySpecialFunction.createdByMe = true;
    return thisIsMySpecialFunction;
}
```

Check if it was created by you like this:

```
if( fun.createdByMe ){

}
```

Comment: I though that solution but is very easy to "hack it". I also though about using Symbol, but is not well supported across all browsers. For now I'm using a special name for the function. Which is a similar solution that you gave.

Comment: If you live by a don't ever trust code runned in the user side then I would say it would always be hackable.
I was trying to think of a way to make a closure with a pointer to an object and compare it with `===` but there was always a way to 'leak' the pointer

Comment: @DiogoAlmiro You could use a `WeakSet` to store the functions in and look it up there if you need absolute encapsulation.

Comment: I think the WeakSet solution is the most efficient. Don't like about not supporting old browsers.